# Anything before and after delimiter regex

Tags: regex, delimiter

```
(?=.+?,*)[^,]+
```

There are the results I get and expect:

"This,is,successful"

Results:

- This
- is
- successful

",is also successful"

Results:

- is also successful

The following is wrong-

"This is not successful"

Results:

- This is not successful

I only want to match if and only if the delimiter is in the string, anything before and after the delimiter. I tried an additional look ahead with `+.`. but was either getting results that include everything or nothing at all when a delimiter like ',' was present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookarounds based regex:

```
(?<=,)[^,]*|[^,]*(?=,)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lX1oR2/2)

- `(?<=,)` asserts there is a `,` before the match
- `(?=,)` asserts there is a `,` after the match
- `[^,]*` matches 0 or more of any character except the comma

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you but so far this is working well with my scenarios in C# code. Its a shame javascript doesn't support the lookbehind though so it may not work for everyone. If someone doesn't come along with a universal solution, I'll mark this as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Yes not sure why it was downvoted. Maybe because I used look-arounds without asking for regex flavor first.

Comment: Here is a version with capturing groups: [`,([^,]*)|([^,]*),`](https://regex101.com/r/lX1oR2/4) and will work almost anywhere.

Comment: It has to match `successful` also in 2nd line

Comment: In the pattern, better use `+` than `*`. Otherwise, you may end up matching spaces if the string is like `  ,  `. Suggest a pattern [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/nT9jT7/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
([^,]+)?,([^,]+)|([^,]+),([^,]+)?
```

Tested on PHP 5.5. (The above regex works well in PHP with `preg_match_all` function)

Comment: At least on regexr.com, I'm noticing several issues with this. "word," doesn't return a match. "word,test" returns the whole string as a result, and I don't want the delimiter in the result either. "word,test,foo" returns 2 matches: word,test - ,why